# when contact form7 submited domain redirects to example.com means (example domain)

Tags: redirect, plugin-contact-form-7

When contact form7 is submitted the domain redirects to Example Domain. Here is the image
[image]

and this image is shown instead of my website page or my domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere you have default code telling the form to redirect to a URL after submission.  This is not default behavior of this plugin, did you add something?

Here are a couple things you can check.

In the admin go to Contact and edit your form, check the Additional Settings tab.  What, if anything, is in there?

If that tab is empty, check elsewhere for code similar to below, this is how you redirect contact form 7 after submission.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        location = 'http://example.com/';
    }, false );
</script>
```